# Object.errors in Ruby on Rails not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form error partial that raises a NoMethodError in Users#new. It says "undefined method `errors` for nil:NilClass

This is the partial I am calling via: `<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>`

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The `new.html.erb` for `users`:

```
<%= simple_form_for :user, url: register_path do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <%= f.input :username, label: false, placeholder: "Username (maximum: 12 characters)", class: "form-control" %>
  <%= f.input :first_last_name, label: false, placeholder: "First & Last Name", class: "form-control" %>
  <%= f.input :email, label: false, placeholder: "Email Address", class: "form-control" %>
  <%= f.input :password, label: false, placeholder: "Create a Password (minimum: 6 characters)", class: "form-control" %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Create an Account!", class: "submit btn btn-block btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

`users_controller`:

```
before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:edit, :update, :show]
before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update, :show]
before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy

def new
  @title = 'Register';
  @user = User.new;
end

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    @user.send_activation_email
    flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

  private

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:username, :first_last_name, :email, :password)
end

# Before filters

# Confirms the correct user.
def correct_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
end

# Confirms an admin user.
def admin_user
  redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
end
```

I don't really understand why this wouldn't be working, Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is there a "blank" user created? Or is it nil like the error implies? Unrelated, but I don't see how the title is related to the question.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change the title. It doesn't seem like it no. (I checked the db via "DB Browser" and I only have users 2 and 3, I deleted the first user using the DB browser. I was testing and made the same user twice, but it didn't raise the error but said the error in my command prompt. I implemented this and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: show us the rest of the code (controller action and form)

Comment: @Julien I added more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the way you are opening the form to this (instead of a symbol pass the object you created in the new action):

```
<%= simple_form_for @user, url: register_path do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thank you it now displays the errors! Would calling the object me required for all forms like this? or only the ones that need to use the `object.errors` exception handler?

Comment: when working on an object you should do it like that, it will allow you also to have the form populated with the object's data when using the form in the edit action